# Configuring Doctrine to Ignore Downed Slaves

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine 2.4 with master/slave configuration in a Symfony application. It seems Doctrine throws an exception when a slave goes down, which brings down the whole site. I'm trying to find a way of configuring or extending Doctrine to simply ignore crashed slaves, which seems to me to be a more sane behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a load balancer in front of the slaves and list the ip of the load balancer as the slave in your doctrine configuration.  The load balancer will take downed slaves out of rotation and your site will stay up when one of the slaves goes down.

Comment: I considered this approach, but I feel it would add unnecessary complexity, and if every slave goes down the web app is still going to crash instead of simply limping along using the master until someone can fix the problem. Ignoring downed slaves or those that have fallen too far out of sync with the master has always been part of any framework I've written, and I'm surprised Doctrine doesn't support such a feature out of the box.

Comment: you could just use a multi-master system then (like a galera cluster - http://galeracluster.com/products/ )